# Manual disk 'mirroring'

Tags: windows-xp, mirroring

I have a situation that I have to manually sync one disk to the other and keep the copy as fresh as possible.  Any (possibly free) software for it?

OS: Windows XP x86

Comment: for specific folders or folders with subfolders, try [Sync Toy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have WinXP Pro, you could keep the two disks in a RAID 1 array so they are automatically mirrored on a filesystem level.

### Edit:

[XXCLONE](http://www.xxclone.com/index.htm) appears to be a simple filesystem cloner that doesn't need to work on a disk I/O level (like by booting a live CD). It seems to be free for whole-disk backups, but has the functionality for faster incremental backups if you pay for the Pro version.

[DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) might be another option.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't. XP doesn't have mirroring enabled :(  I thought that it would be an option, and was greatly surprised that it isn't.

Comment: Oh well, such is Microsoft. Maybe the software listed above will help?

Comment: I found the SyncTOY that is ok with me - it can even be scheduled via command line version.